# Logging Incorrect login attempts to Apache error.log file

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, joomla, apache2

I want to log all the incorrect login attempts of the following Apache services: Joomla, Wordpress, PhpMyAdmin.

All the incorrect login attempts should be placed in the file named `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or any user defined file. Any approach to do so will be immense help!

Answer (score 0):

First thing, Joomla, Wordpress, PhpMyAdmin are not apache services. They are web application can be hosted under any web server like apache. Since incorrect login attempt is not an error for apache, you cannot log them under apache error log. You may use application logs for this purpose.